# How many horses can I own?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

So I already know I can stable 3 horses and ride one, but I’m just curious how many horses can I actually have? I find myself wanting to tame more horses and I don’t want to lose any of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can only have the four horses - the ones in the stable and the one you're on.

It is possible to have another "temporary" horse out in the wild, but I have no idea how long it would last.